# How to solve $0.5^{1200}\times (2^{1204})$?

Tags: exponentiation

I've been struggling with this one. I know that the anwser is $16$, but how do I solve this on paper?

$0.5^{1200}\times 2^{1204}$

I know that this has something to do with first subtracting the "powers of n" from each other, but... Step by step is much appreciated!

Comment: $.5=2^{-1}$ would be my main hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$0.5^{1200}\times  2^{1204}=\frac{1}{2^{1200}}\times  2^{1204}=\frac{2^{1204}}{2^{1200}}=2^{1204-1200}=2^4=16$$

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1200}\cdot2^{1204}=2^{-1200}\cdot2^{1204}=2^{-1200+1204}=2^4$

Answer (score 0):

$(0.5)^{1200} = (\frac{1}{2})^{1200} = (2^{-1})^{1200} = 2^{(-1)\cdot1200} = 2^{-1200}$

$2^{-1200} \cdot 2^{1204} = 2^{-1200+1204} = 2^4 = 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2 = 16$

Answer (score 0):

$0.5^{1200}\cdot2^{1204}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{1200}\cdot2^{1204}=\dfrac{1^{1200}\cdot2^{1204}}{2^{1200}}=1\cdot 2^4=16.$