# Right way to solve for $\frac{2^{900}*7^{898}}{14^{897}}$

Tags: exponentiation

As a sequel to my question [How to solve $0.5^{1200}\times (2^{1204})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/968073/how-to-solve-0-51200-times-21204) :

$\frac{2^{900}*7^{898}}{14^{897}}$

Will I first solve the upper raw like did in previous question and then anwser $14^{897}$

Comment: First of all, this has nothing to do with parsing order. You are asking for a faster way of computing it, which has nothing to do with parsing order and everything to do with factorization and various properties of multiplication/division.

Comment: Sry, by parsing I meant the calculation order of solving this one... english is not my strongest...

Comment: Okay. For what it is worth, "parsing" is how you read something, not how you do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{2^{900}\cdot 7^{898}}{14^{897}} = \frac{2^{900}\cdot 7^{898}}{(2\cdot 7)^{897}} = \frac{2^{900}\cdot 7^{898}}{2^{897}\cdot 7^{897}}$$ $$= 2^{900 - 897}\cdot 7^{898-897} = 2^3\cdot 7^1 = 8\cdot 7 = 56$$

Comment: Check your equation again... I and the textbook got 64... maybe me and the textbook were both wrong...

Comment: My answer is correct, given the expression you posted. Perhaps you made a typo on exponents in your post?

Comment: No, there must be error in my textbook. I've alread found one with my teacher... Thanks @amWhy